# Jar file compiled using JDK-11 in eclipse is not running in fedora with jdk 8

Tags: java

I has compiled and made an executable jar file in windows 7 using eclipse IDE and Java JDK-11. I tried to run the same file in fedora 30 which has JDK-8 but it did not run.

Here is the error message:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Practice/Clock has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Comment: 1) You can get Java 11 for Fedora 30.  2) If you want your code to run on Java 8, the simplest thing is to compile it on Java 8.

Comment: Sure, but if this is so what is the use of leaning java instead of C++ if I am going to face this dependency problem. C++ is way more powerful and more software oriented language though little complex?

Comment: It is not complex once you understand it.  (In fact, the principle is really simple.  Compile on the oldest version you want to support.)  But if you think this is too complex, nobody is forcing you to use Java instead of C++ :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54439762/java-jdk-11-breaking-old-jars-programs